# "Or" operator is not working as expected in R

Tags: r, if-statement, logical-operators

I am trying to created a function as below:

```
remove_loan_apl <- function(x) {
  if((x==0) || (is.NA(x))) {x <- 100000} 
   return(x)
}
remove_loan_apl <- function(x) {
  if((x==0) || (x is NA)) {x <- 100000} 
   return(x)
}
```

But its not working. What is the correct method to apply or for the missing value?
I expect the function to replace value of x to 100000, where it is 0 or missing(NA)

Comment: You are missing a terminal parantheses. Remember to close the if statement. And functions are case-sensitive `is.NA` is not an R function.

Comment: sorry, that unbalanced parentheses was by mistake.

Comment: I also tried this:  remove_loan_apl <- function(x) {
  if((x==0) || (x==NA)) {x <- 100000} 
  else if(x>1500000){x<-1500000}
  return(x)
}

Comment: `if( x == 0 || is.na(x)) {x <- 1e5}` should be fine. But the question fails to mention what this function is expected to do. If you provide an example of sample data input and output, it's easier to give more detailed help.

Comment: well, ( x == 0 || is.na(x)) seems to be working, not sure why if((x==0) || (is.NA(x))) is not working

Comment: As @PierreLafortune said, `is.NA` is not an R function.

Comment: ah, i hate case sensitivity of R. How can i remove the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

May be I can guess what you are doing.

This function as suggested by Pierre Lafortune

```
remove_loan_apl <- function(x) {
    if((x==0) || (is.na(x))) {x <- 100000} 
    return(x)
}
```

should work.

I think what you are trying to do is pass a complete vector of mixed values non-na,0 and NA to x. If you pass a complete vector this function will not work and will return your vector as it is.

For eg.

```
x=c(1,NA,2,3,NA,4,0,5)
```

If you will do

```
remove_loan_apl(x)
```

It will return x vector as it is.

Output :

```
1 NA  2  3 NA  4  0  5
```

You will have to lapply or sapply to apply your function to each and every value of your vector.

```
sapply(x,remove_loan_apl)
```

This will give the output as desired :

```
1 100000      2      3 100000      4 100000      5
```

Comment: that should work too. use `mapply(remove_loan_apl,x)`